# Linear Algebra Invertible Matrix Theorem Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Part of the proof for this theorem asks you to show that if $A$ is an $n \times n$-matrix and there exists an $n \times n$-matrix $D$ such that $AD = I$ (the $n \times n$-identity matrix), then the equation $Ax = b$ has at least one solution for each $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In order to prove this, I simply started with the hypothesis that $AD = I$ and right-multiplied each side of the equation by the $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector $b$ to get:

$AD(b) = I(b) = b.$

By the associative property for matrix multiplication, this leads to $A(Db) = b$, which means that for every $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the vector $Db$ is a solution so that $Ax = b$ has at least that one solution for every $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm pretty sure that's one way of proving it, but can anyone give me any hints about a different or possibly more insightful way of proving this step? It's definitely one of the least straight-forward inferences in the theorem.

Comment: Your proof is correct although (depending on your professor) it can be written much more succinctly. For example: for all $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, if we let $x=Db\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $Ax=A(Db)=(AD)b=Ib=b$.

Comment: @Meta = welcome to math.stackexchange! This is correct and it is probably the most straight forward way to prove it. I also like the good pace (no gaps, no jumps, no stalling) in your argument.

Answer (score 1):

The OP thought that his proof/argument was somehow not straightforward. Actually, in the theory of sets it is well known that $f \circ g = 1_{id} \text{ iff } f \text{ is surjective and } g \text{ is injective}$. His argument actually does not use linear algebra and is used in the more general context.

So, in passing, I felt obliged to mention that the argument is indeed straightforward, albeit abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint to another approach: There exists a $D$ such that $AD = I$ if and only if the column space of $A$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.